# How to call a function after click on input to chose image then button show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I want to put something instead of on select for show button in fileup plugin after loaded all images.

```js
$.fileup({
  url: '/photo-gallery/api/photo/new/',
  inputID: 'upload-demo',
  queueID: 'upload-demo-queue',
  fieldName: 'original_photo',
  autostart: false,
  extraFields: {
    'title': title,
    'uploaded_photo_set_title': $("#uploaded_photo_set_title").val()
  },
  onSelect: function(file) {
    $('.next-session-upload').removeClass('none');
  },
  onSuccess: function(response, file_number, file) {
    $('.waiting-msg').addClass('none');
    $('.for-success').removeClass('none');
    succsees_file_count = succsees_file_count + 1;
    if (succsees_file_count + error_file_count === countOfUpload) {
      window.location = "/photo-gallery/photo/new/" + jQuery.parseJSON(response).uploaded_photo_set_id + "/complete";
    }
  },
  onError: function(event, file, file_number) {
    $('.next-session-upload').removeClass('none');
    $('.for-error').addClass('block-alert');
    error_file_count = error_file_count + 1;
    alert(error_file_count);
    if (succsees_file_count + error_file_count === countOfUpload) {
      window.location = "/photo-gallery/photo/new/" + jQuery.parseJSON(response).uploaded_photo_set_id + "/complete";
    }
  },
  onStart: function(file_number, file) {
    $('.waiting-msg').removeClass('none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="original_photo" type="file" id="upload-demo" multiple="" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/Tiff,image/NEF,image/Raw,image/CR2,image/">
```

Comment: Post your HTML!

Comment: <input name="original_photo" type="file" id="upload-demo" multiple="" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/Tiff,image/NEF,image/Raw,image/CR2,image/">

Comment: Now can you emphasise your problem ?

Comment: yes, when i upload images before all image loaded the button shows, i want wait for loaded all image then show the button

Comment: Sorry mate I don't think this plugin provides the callback for on complete all so I think you need to customize this plugin before using it.

Comment: i think so.. but thank you a lot .